# PartialView is not updating

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, partial-views

Tried to update table data without reload using partial view. Why after controller action my table is not updating?

in my partial view *_usersTable*:

```
@model IEnumerable<Task1.Models.ApplicationUser>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.userCheck, new { id = item.Id }) 
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

in my main view:

```
<table id="myTable">
    @Html.Partial("_usersTable")
</table>

<script>
    function deleteRecords() {
        var selected = [];
        $('#myTable input:checked').each(function () {
            selected.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/DeleteRecords',
            type: 'POST',
            traditional: true,
            data: { array: selected }
        });
    }
</script>
```

controller action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult DeleteRecords(string[] array)
    {
        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext(getContextOptions()))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Count(); i++)
            {
                ApplicationUser user = context.Users.Find(array[i]);
                context.Users.Remove(user);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();          
            return PartialView("_usersTable", context.Users.ToList());
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Why after controller action my table is not updating?". Quite simply because you haven't written any code which would update it. You need to do something with the response from your ajax call. Right now you're not even handling the response from the call (which would contain the updated HTML for the partial view). There are lots of tutorials/examples of this online...did you try any?

Comment: @ADyson             `success:(function(result) {
                $('#myTable').html(result);
            })` this working, thanks